# Create a function with return type of image magick object in go lang

Tags: go, imagick, go-imagick

I want to create image magick object corresponding to images stroed in S3. So, i was writing a function which will take necessary arguments and return the image magick object. But, no luck with it. This is the [Imagick Library](https://github.com/gographics/imagick) which i am using.

```
     func main() {
        mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
        defer mw.Destroy()
        mw = ObjImagick(bucketName, keyName, region)
    }



  func ObjImagick(bktName string, kName string, region string) ( ) {

    s3Client := s3.New(session.New(), &aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})
        params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bktName),
        Key: aws.String(kName),
        }

    out, err := s3Client.GetObject(params)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    img, err := ioutil.ReadAll(out.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }      

    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()

    err = mw.ReadImageBlob(img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

       return mw
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [`NewMagickWand()`](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/blob/943dd0909306f8bea46cc7f855de8ae6790730d4/imagick/magick_wand.go#L25) returns a `*MagickWand`, so you can create your function like:

```
func ObjImagick(bktName string, kName string, region string) *imagick.MagickWand {
    .......................
    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    // defer mw.Destroy() this destroys the wand when ObjMagick returns.
    // so you can't do this here, your func caller needs to handle destroying the object.

    err = mw.ReadImageBlob(img)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return mw
}
```

Then the caller has to call `.Destroy()`, for example:

```
func main() {
    mw := ObjImagick(bucketName, keyName, region)
    defer mw.Destroy()
}
```

Comment: Could you please also tell me how to evenly crop an image just passing the aspect ratio not cropping coordinates.  `imgStream.Crop((int)originalWidth, ((int)(originalWidth / masterAspectRatio)), Gravity.Center)` like we do it in .net

Comment: @Naresh I'm not sure, I've never used it before.